# Repeating keys on external keyboards (usb, bluetooth and dongle) with windows 10 surface book 2

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I attached an external keyboard to my surface book 2, windows 10. FIrst I tried with a wireless Bluetooth one, but once every 5 minutes some of the keys keeps repeaaaaaaaating randomly. So I returned that keyboard and got a different one, this time one with a dongle. Same problem. I plugged in the USB dongle in different places, a hub, a second hub, directly the the computer. Same problem. So I got a wired keyboard. Same problem again. Therefore this must a driver/windows issue. Any suggestions how to tackle it? many thanks

Comment: Try using Windows Safe Mode, as well as uninstalling and re-installing HID Keyboard Device from Device Manager.

Comment: why do I have 5 HID keyboard devices?

Comment: I had this issue. I still do have this issue and it is driving me insane. Both USB and Bluetooth keyboards do this on my Surface Book 3. Reformatted my laptop yesterday, did a clean install and it is still happening.

Comment: Yea I gave up using any external keyboard with the surface book 2

Comment: @Nickpick today I ran Powershell with admin access and disabled Intel's Turbo Boost but have not been able to test with an external keyboard yet. Do you think it's an issue unique to Surface Books? Do you have other devices using Win 10?

Comment: @Nickpick something else you could try: https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/aujg3d/fix_naughty_usbintroducing_a_ridiculous_usb_bug/

Comment: @Nickpick unfortunately nothing has helped me either. Trying to get it refunded or swapped with a MacBook Pro.

Comment: I've had the same problem with an external keyboard on a MacBook Air (2020) -- but it only happens in my work office (swapped my work and home keyboards to no effect), so it probably is interference coming from another office.  It only happens intermittently but then it's like that for an hour or so.

Answer (score 4):

I have had this issue precisely on my Windows 10 system amd trawled the web for answers. The answers are inadequate, theoretical guesses - and miss the point. My problem was resolved by switching off the extra unused networking capabilities associated with my HP Office jet printer - Bluetooth and WiFi Direct. HP pumps out frequencies looking for connections every so often and that activity potentially overwhelms the Bluetooth bandwidth. The repeated key syndrome happens when a key signal is being successfully sent but not acknowledged and it is resent (potentially a series of times).  Sometimes it is the sending signal that is interrupted and so nothing happens. From daily instances of this problem I went straight to zero (for 4 weeks now) by turning off HP WiFi Direct and HP Bluetooth (using simply regular WiFi only for the printer). If you do not use  an HP printer have a look at what else you may have generating competing Bluetooth signals and try turning off or restricting those devices.

Comment: Not sure it’s connected to Bluetooth. My Logitech keyboard also offers a proprietary wireless connection and the problem occurs as well

Comment: @Nickpick That might very well be the case, because many manufacturers use license-free bands (frequencies). From these, 2.4 GHz is most widely used (Bluetooth, early WiFi, and a bunch of other techniques). That means that this HP equipment may disturb not only Bluetooth devices, but others as well.

Comment: Actually I even have the problem when connected to cable